# aws-vpc containers do not have access to the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I created ECS service in AWS ECS cluster. 
My container uses the awsvpc network mode. The service has no load balancer.

But it cannot touch any public internet resources.

When I go to the ECS instance and ssh into docker container I cannot wget any public resources.

```
root@ip-10-3-1-23:/app# traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *^C
```

```
root@ip-10-3-1-23:/app# wget google.com
--2019-08-31 22:34:38--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.9.206, 2607:f8b0:4004:807::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.9.206|:80... ^C
root@ip-10-3-1-23:/app#
```

EC2 instance security group:

Inbound:

```
Type            Protocol        Port Range      Source                      Description
All TCP         TCP             0 - 65535       10.3.0.0/16     
SSH             TCP             22              sg-5c260123 (mgmt-bastion)  
Custom TCP Rule TCP             51678           sg-0784b8f53ab37c234 (mgmt-jenkins-sg)
```

Outbound:

```
Type            Protocol        Port Range      Source                      Description
All traffic     All             All             0.0.0.0/0
```

Service security group:

Inbound:

```
Type            Protocol        Port Range      Source                      Description
All TCP         TCP             0 - 65535       10.3.0.0/16
```

Outbound:

```
Type            Protocol        Port Range      Source                      Description
All traffic     All             All             0.0.0.0/0
```

Could you help me debug it, how to allow for internet access, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) :

> The awsvpc network mode does not provide task ENIs with public IP addresses for tasks that use the EC2 launch type. **To access the internet, tasks that use the EC2 launch type must be launched in a private subnet that is configured to use a NAT gateway**. For more information, see NAT Gateways in the Amazon VPC User Guide. Inbound network access must be from within the VPC using the private IP address or DNS hostname, or routed through a load balancer from within the VPC. Tasks launched within public subnets do not have outbound network access.

Comment: Yeah, i found it just 20 minutes ago and moving this task to the private subnet. :) I will update results when finish. Thank you it was the solution! :)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue but I placed the EC2 nodes in public subnets that should have internet connection directly but the task can’t reach internet while the host does.

Comment: @RuBiCK, have you solved the problem? I did exactly the same thing, but container cannot access the internet

Comment: @slesh Yes, I solved the problem but I work on several projects and I don't remember what I did. I think it was a routing problem and also a network mode of the service or containers. If you want me to check specific configuration, let me know

Comment: or change the network type from **awsvpc** to **bridge** in the task definition to enable container networks on linux EC2 instances.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue by adding one entry in the Route table for subnet where the ECS task is created in.

```
Destination       Target 
10.3.0.0/16       local
0.0.0.0/0         nat-02dcc4c6b32bdae00
```

Comment: Interesting, when I do the same thing, then I cannot ssh my ec2 where tasks are running

Comment: Do you use public IP or private ip to SSH? Try to debug it with the following steps:
1) Allow All Traffic from entire internet in the instance SG, then you can try SSH, 
2) Check if you can ping your instance
3) Then check your Network ACLs

Comment: All these requirements are met. I use public ip to ssh. Not sure what reason that I lost ssh access...