# Curl from inside an ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to call curl from within my container.

```
docker exec -it 07d curl www.google.com
```

Which gives me a timeout. I am using the `awsvpc` network. Curl is installed on the container. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing to try is making sure that the subnets associated with the ECS container have internet access or not. Not sure how experienced you are with AWS however the subnets are of two types, one public and other private. The easiest way to check is, click on all the subnets configured with your cluster where the containers are and then click on the route table associated with those subnets. If you see a route like 0.0.0.0 -> igw-* or 0.0.0.0 -> nat-*, this means that the subnets have internet connection.
Are you using Fargate? Also try with `curl www.google.com -vv` for verbose

Comment: There is a igw attached to the subnets. So that seems to be OK.

Getting the following response on the curl call:
```
*   Trying 172.253.116.103:80...
*   Trying 2a00:1450:400b:c00::69:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:400b:c00::69: Address not available
```

I am using ECS with containers, no fargate.

Comment: To me it still seems to be a network issue. Same with `ping 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: Yeah, getting the following 
`--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---`
`43 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss`

Comment: Started flow logs, and got this weird response there:
`2021-04-10T14:37:41.000+02:002 XXXX eni-0ed8469c31fcd8c60 - - - - - - - 1618058261 1618058263 - SKIPDATA2 452797736277 eni-0ed8469c31fcd8c60 - - - - - - - 1618058261 1618058263 - SKIPDATA`

Comment: Ah it seems my task does not have a public IP, and the ENI of the task is not visible in the EC2 instance, under Network Interfaces.

Comment: So essentially the problem boils down to having the internet access. Looks like it's gonna work if you move the task to a private subnet. A NAT Gateway in the public subnet will be needed as well. The private subnet where you are going to move your task should have a default route like 0.0.0.0 --> NAT Gateway. Please see this - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741658/10846194